# ADF: How to get path of file when using InputFile Component

Tags: oracle-adf

I am using jdeveloper version 11.1.1.5.0. In my use case I have created Mail Client Send Mail program where I used  ADF InputFile component to attach File on mail.

But problem is that InputFile Component only return path of file(only get file name). And in my mail program DataSource class use full path to access file name.

```
 UploadedFile uploadfile=(UploadedFile) actionEvent.getNewValue();
 String fname= uploadfile.getFilename();//this line only get file name.
```

So how can I get full path using adf InputFile component or any other way to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: Why do you want to do that @Manish, you can easily get the file content using uploadFile.getInputStream() and you can wrap it inside a file object of your choice if you want!

Answer (score 1):

You could save the uploaded file in a path at the server. Only take care about naming that file, because of concurrency of users you should follow a policy about it, for example, adding te time in milliseconds to the name of the file. Like this...

```
private String writeToFile(UploadedFile file) {
    ServletContext servletCtx =
        (ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
    String fileDirPath = servletCtx.getRealPath("/files/tmp");
    String fileName = getTimeInMilis()+file.getFilename();
    try {

        InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os =
            new FileOutputStream(fileDirPath + "/"+fileName);
        int readData;
        while ((readData = is.read()) != -1) {
            os.write(readData);
        }
        is.close();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fileName;
}
```

This method also returns the new name of the uploaded file. You can replace getTimeInMilis() with any naming policy you like.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a security issue if a web app is able to see anything other than the data stream for an uploaded file. The directory structure of the client would not be exposed to the webapp. As such, unless you plan to upload the file from the same host as the server, you will not have access to the file path on the client.

Note: Using answer instead of comment due to reputation threshold